# Is there any way through which server communicates with iPhone app without app asking for data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

Is there any way through which server can deliver data (ex. any status change) to app without app asking for it.
For example I want server to deliver user status to app if there is any change without app keep asking for it.
I know of push notifications(even silent push notification), is there any other way (preferably silent way)?

Comment: push notifications can be silent, as far as i know

Comment: You need to use Sockets, this is what it was for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fairly simple:

[PushNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

Or more complicated:

[Sockets and Apple class for them NSStream](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html)

[Reading From Input Stream](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/ReadingInputStreams.html)

Answer (score 0):

The http protocol relies on the request/response cycle so the server can not initiate communication in that scenario. If you really have a need for this you need to use another protocol stack that enables the server to keep a open connection so it can initiate communication. I don't really know what would be the best way to go here, maybe looking in to Web Sockets. I do think it's quite a lot of work.